# Prove or disprove: Let S be a subset of X, where X has metrics d1, d2 (d1(x,y)<d2(x,y)). If S is open with d2, then it is open with d1

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Given a set X with two metrics d1, d2 that follow the property such that d1(x,y $<$ d2(x,y)) for all x,y. Prove or disprove: 
i) Assume S is a subset of X. If S is open with d2, then S is open with d1. 
ii) Assume S is a subset of X. If S is open with d1, then S is open with d2.

I have tried this, but not sure if it is correct. Suppose S is open with d2, then we can form a ball of radium r, center at x (x belonging to S) such that B(x,r2) is contained in S. Since d1(x,y) < d2(x,y), then B(x, r1) will be contained in B(x,r2) which is contained in S. Hence, it is true.

The other one I think is false, but cannot come up with a counterexample.

Comment: I have edited with what I did @neth. Hope this helps

Comment: The first is true for the reason you cite.  For the second let $d_1 (x,y) = ||x-y||/(||x-y||+1) $ and $d_2 (x,y)=1$ if x and y aren't equal.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean $d_1(x,y)\leq d_2(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$ (otherwise, what is $d_1(x,x)$?)

It looks like you got a bit turned around in your reasoning. Notice that 
$$B_{d_2}(s,r)=\{x:d_2(s,x)<r\}\subset\{x:d_1(s,x)<r\}=B_{d_1}(s,r)$$
as $$d_2(s,x)<r\implies d_1(s,x)\leq d_2(s,x)<r.$$
Therefore, $S$ open under $d_1$ implies that $S$ open under $d_2$ (why?)

For a counterexample to the other statement, consider $X=[0,1]$, set $d_1$ to be the usual (Euclidean) metric, and set $d_2$ to be the standard discrete metric.

Comment: You are saying that ii) is true, but i) is false. Wouldn't it be the opposite?

Comment: I have a proof for (ii) and a counterexample to (i). Why would it be the opposite?

Comment: Since the d1 < d2, if open with d2, wouldn't it also be open with d1 since we can form a smaller ball with that distance? That is why I thought it was the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Let $d_2(x,y) = d_1 (x,y)+1$.  Then $B_{1/2}(x) =X $ So every set is open.